# ASP.NET MVC 5 jpg logo and favicon

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-403, favicon

After publishing to the local IIS a web application the header logo image and favicon throw an error 403.

Logo:`<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/logo.jpg")" class="navbar-left" />`

Favicon is in the root.

The application pool run in the name of an AD user.
I've given the full right to Everyone to the app folder with inheritance.
Everithing's OK but these two images. Please, help me.

Comment: Check files owner. Try create new images in paint and replace old images with new just created.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must convert your image to a png format. kindly go through this steps:

1. Go to this: http://www.favicon-generator.org/
2. Download & Extract the favicons.
3. Choose the size & Replace the code like this :

   ```
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="64x64" href="@Url.Content("@Url.Content("~/Content/favicon-64x64.png")">
   ```

Comment: Thank you but the image and favicon are displayed in prod server thus this problem origins from my local machine iis wrong configuration.

Comment: Then try to reinstall your iis server and try like this. I think it might work well.